# Yii2 password reset email, view not found

Tags: yii2

I'm using yii2's advanced template, with default functionalities of user auth system, here in frontend's site/request-password-reset page, when i'm entering email and click on send button, i'm getting the following error:

> The view file does not exist:
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\yii2_advanced\frontend/mail\passwordResetToken-html.php

looks like it's looking for the view in frontend instead of common, what do i need to do to fix it?

Comment: try this `getAlias('@common').'/mail/passwordResetToken-html.php'`

Comment: @G4M1TG, well, i tried `return \Yii::$app->mailer->compose(['html' => \Yii::getAlias('@common').'\passwordResetToken-html', 'text' => 'passwordResetToken-text'], ['user' => $user])` , but it appends frontend's url at the begining.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@app` alias in your path

```
return \Yii::$app->mailer->compose([
        'html' => '@app/common/mail/passwordResetToken-html',      
        'text' => '@app/common/mail/passwordResetToken-text'
    ], ['user' => $user]);
```

Comment: um, sorry, but it still including 'frontend' in the url, besides, i wonder why do i need to change the default scaffolding for this, i think it worked well without and modification in previous project.